# Replacing a character from a string in C

Tags: c, replace, char, c-strings, function-definition

I tried with this method but the output remains the same as the input. The user enters the character he wants to replace and with which letter he wants to replace with. I don't understand where did I go wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* replaceChar(char *s, char x,char y)
{
    int i=0;
    while(s[i])
    {
        if(s[i]==x)
        {
            s[i]==y;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return s;

}

int main()
{
    char string[30];

    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    gets(string);
    fflush(stdin);
    char x;
    char y;
    printf("Enter the character you want to replace:\n");
    scanf("%c",&x);
    printf("Enter the character you want to replace with:\n");
    scanf(" ");
    scanf("%c",&y);

    printf("After replacing the string :\n");
    printf("%s",replaceChar(&string[0],x,y));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obligatory: [Never use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10077)

Comment: `"%c"` --> `" %c"`

Comment: Change double equals to single: s[i]=y

Comment: Thanks
should i use fgets() instead of gets here?

Comment: Yes, use `fgets()`. And be aware that it leaves the `\n` in the resulting string, which `gets()` does not.

Comment: It's always helpful to include sample input and expected and actual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that instead of the assignment operator you are using the comparison operator in this code snippet

```
    if(s[i]==x)
    {
        s[i] == y;
    }
```

Write

```
    if(s[i]==x)
    {
        s[i] = y;
    }
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Instead use the function `fgets`.

Also this call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior. Remove it.

And use

```
scanf(" %c",&x);
      ^^^

scanf(" %c",&y);
      ^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c",&x);
scanf(" ");
scanf("%c",&y);
```